# Determine if f: Z × Z → Z is onto

Tags: functions

This is the solution I found:

[image]

Why does the pairing (0,-x) work to prove the whole function is onto?

Comment: Just recall the definition of onto functions. For every element $b$ in $\Bbb{Z}$, can we find some (at least one) element in $\Bbb{Z} \times \Bbb{Z}$ such that it maps to $b$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show the function is onto we need to show that every element in the range is the image of at least one element of the domain.  This does exactly that.  It says if you give me an $x \in \Bbb Z$ I can find you an element $y \in \Bbb {Z \times Z}$ such that $f(y)=x$ and the one I find is $(0,-x)$.  Other examples are possible, for example $(2,-x+4)$, but we only need one.